# Header location in javascript

Tags: javascript

is it possible to in javascript like in php header location, if the visitor comes from index html alert something? and how ? thank you

Comment: Can you clarify that question a bit? At the moment people will be guessing at what you're asking.

Comment: I think he is talking about the REFERER: if visitors come from index.html, alert something. In that case, use the History object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(document.referrer == url){ alert(msg); }
```

Should do it.

Comment: +1 Wow. Had never heard of that, works in Chrome, IE7, and Firefox *at least*.

Answer (score 2):

Check the referrer, but you most likely will need the absolute uri, like this:

```
if (document.referrer == 'http://domain.com/index.html')
    alert('How was the index?');
```

Comment: You could of course use the match() method like so if(document.referrer.match("index.php")){ alert(msg) }, but as you rightly say full URL is probably the best idea since it will prevent cross domain matches.